How to read this type of data from a UART in the proper way
I just can not find a proper solution for this types of data returns from a Quectel device. There is an echo and CRLFanswerCRLF template.
There are blanks between data and fills buffer:

I tried IDLE line detection with UART DMA, but when the device receives "AT\r", it prints out " A T  ", fill the memory with ASCII null (\0), stops receiving, and prints " ".
Also, I tried UART DMA receive and made the buffer length exactly to fit all data. In the picture, you can see the last data fills the buffer, but the device doesn't get in the interrupt and that's it.
I don't know how to do it with a proper way without reading data byte by byte and don't want to keep the MCU busy all the time. How can I do it?
There is the raw data from the device and my translation to ASCII: "41540D0D0A4F4B0D0A" (AT\r\r\nOK\r\n)
Also I didn't understand why there are blanks between characters. Am I missing something?
Here are my arrays:
uint8_t RxBuffer[64];
uint8_t TxStart[] = "Device opened\r\n";
uint8_t TxSent[]  = "Sent\r\n";
uint8_t TxReceived[] = "Received\r\n";

Here is my receive code:
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
  if (huart->Instance == USART1)
  {
    AT_response_send(RxBuffer);
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer));
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
  }
}

Here are the AT functions:
void AT_send(char msg[])
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg), 1000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, TxSent, sizeof(TxSent), 1000);
}

void AT_response_send(uint8_t msg[])
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, TxReceived, sizeof(TxReceived), 1000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, msg, strlen((const char *)msg), 1000);
}

And here is the starting code:
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, TxStart, sizeof(TxStart), 1000);
  AT_send("AT\r");
  HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer));
  __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);

USART and DMA configuration:
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;

For USART 1:
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;

For USART 2:
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;

Init function for USART1 and its DMA:
PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
PeriphClkInitStruct.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

/* USART1 clock enable */
__HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
/** USART1 GPIO Configuration
PB7     ------> USART1_RX
PB6     ------> USART1_TX
*/
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_6;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USART1 DMA Init */
/* USART1_RX Init */
hdma_usart1_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_USART1_RX;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart1_rx) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

if (HAL_DMA_ConfigChannelAttributes(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_CHANNEL_NPRIV) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

__HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle, hdmarx, hdma_usart1_rx);

/* USART1 interrupt Init */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);

Init function for USART2:
PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
PeriphClkInitStruct.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

/* USART2 clock enable */
__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
/** USART2 GPIO Configuration
PA3     ------> USART2_RX
PA2     ------> USART2_TX
*/
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = T_VCP_RX_Pin|T_VCP_RXA2_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USART2 interrupt Init */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

DMA init
void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
}

This code runs like this (raw data from the terminal):
D44 e65 v76 i69 c63 e65  20 o6F p70 e65 n6E e65 d64  0D  0A  00 S53
e65 n6E t74  0D  0A  00 R52 e65 c63 e65 i69 v76 e65 d64  0D  0A  00 R52 e65 c63
e65 i69 v76 e65 d64  0D  0A  00  0D

At the same time, the buffer is:
[]
Also the explaining in the datasheet of the GSM module is here:

By default, the module is in auto-baud mode. When powering on the
module, the MCU has to send AT command consecutively to synchronize
baud rate with the module until OK is returned

and

The AT or at prefix must be added at the beginning of each command
line. Entering  will terminate a command line. Commands are
usually followed by a response that includes
. Throughout this document, only the
response  will be presented,  are omitted
intentionally.


Can you post your receive logic (the function which writes to the destination buffer)?

Can it be a data type issue, like some uint32_t where it should be uint8_t? Please provide a [mre].

Can you also post the UART and DMA configurations?

Code updated any missing?

https://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/99172.htm

@HansPassant How can I implement this and how can I use this can you make it a bit more clear.

Read the modem manual or call the vendor. UTF32 is pretty unusual, surely you can send a command with a terminal emulator to switch it to ASCII or UTF8 permanently.

This is definitely not a Unicode issue because this kind of device produce ASCII output (either text or hex) or RAW binary output for DATA.

Can you try disabling the DMA for UART1 in order to read the incoming data byte by byte (from the ISR function) and confirm the behavior is the same? printf("%02x ", data)

@Jib I implemented as HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1, RxBuffer, 64, 5000);   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, RxBuffer, 64, 100); and get Flaming Error

@bulut I meant using the _IT HAL helpers

@jib Problem solved but i didn't understand why is it working now and how can I implement it without keeping busy the cpu or how can I improve it, any suggestion?

@bulut what do you mean by problem solved? Do you mean that printing the char fron the isr gives the expected response sequence?

The problem is close to what has been mentioned previously, but not so much to do with C types but the fact you've setup your DMA to fetch and write words (which in STM32 are 4 bytes) and not bytes. You should be able to just make the hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment configuration DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE instead (the peripheral side might still have to be DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD for reasons and it should still work from my skimming of the reference manual). Not posted as an answer as I'm not 100% sure it will work fine, but it is where the gaps are coming from.

@Jib yes ISR gives the exactly the expected response, thank you but it has a space in front of idk why, anyway I'm just curious about how can I improve it to be work with variable lenght responses from module; also,I will try Unn's answer below to improve my code
